# "Frauen die lesen sind gefährlich." vs "Frauen, die lesen, sind gefährlich. "

Tags: sentence-structure

Regarding the difference between the sentences above:

I'm confused about the commas. Does the bit ", die lesen," imply that women in general read, and that they are dangerous? Or does the title imply "Those women who read are dangerous."

The version with commas is the title of a bestseller by Stefan Bollmann. The complete title is "Frauen, die lesen, sind gefährlich. Lesende Frauen in Malerei und Fotografie".

The English title became: "Women Who Read Are Dangerous" not "Women, Who Read, Are Dangerous"

Answer (score 10):

The sentence means "[Those] women who read are dangerous".

The commas are mandatory because "die lesen" is a subclause (a *Relativsatz*) and a subclause must be separated from the main clause by commas (§74 of the official rules). Comma rules differ between German and English.

Comment: What are the "official rules"?

Comment: @QuoraFeans https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/

Comment: Note that the commas change the meaning in English; with commas it implies all women read, and without it's similar to "Those women..." I'm still unclear on how the German version isn't ambiguous.

Comment: @RDBury - "with commas it implies all women read" - This meaning does not exist in German.

Comment: @mic: I don't see why. Grammatically, *Naomi, die liest, ist gefährlich* and *Frauen, die lesen, sind gefährlich* seem identical except for a change in subject, but one says Naomi reads, and the other does not say women read. The answer by Carsten S seems to imply that it is ambiguous and the ambiguity is resolved by context, which happens all the time in any language. But this answer seems to say that there is no other possible reading, which I found confusing.

Comment: @RDBury: The sentences are not quite identical IMHO. There is a slight difference in that "Naomi" is already a specific subject. Thus, any relative clause can only be non-defining, as the subject is already defined. "Frauen", on the other hand, is unspecific. Thus, the relative clause "die lesen" will almost definitely be perceived as a defining relative clause. If you want to add a non-defining info, you'd write it differently, e.g. "Frauen lesen und sind gefährlich." or maybe "Frauen, die übrigens/nebenbei bemerkt lesen, sind gefährlich." to indicate you are relaying non-defining info.

Comment: @RDBury, furthermore I would argue that the ambiguity exists only in written German. If you read the sentence out aloud, the "sentence melody" (no idea whether that term makes sense in English) will be different depending on which meaning is intended.

Comment: @Carsten S: Intonation is also used in English, and presumably most other languages, to resolve ambiguity. For example "Would you like juice or soda?" has different meanings depending on the "melody". In this case it's a book title so there is no spoken version, unless there's an audiobook somewhere. I think what's happening is that you can infer the meaning from context and use that to read with the correct intonation. I'm still a learner so that process is more difficult for me and I tend to rely solely on the grammar.

Answer (score 5):

The distinction between defining and non-defining relative clauses with regards to commas does not exist in German. Commas are mandatory in both cases. When reading, you will have to decide from context or by common sense which one it is.